# Completely Capitalize Text in an Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, capitalization, capitalize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the input to uppercase as it is being typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724972/how-to-change-the-input-to-uppercase-as-it-is-being-typed)

Is it possible to completely capitalize text of an input with JavaScript.

So basically as the user is typing the text in the input the text is being capitalized like this: **CAPITALIZE**

Can anybody show me an example on like a fiddle or something? Thanks

Comment: The `text-transform` property will not change the static content, just restyle it, I was wondering how I can actually change the content

Comment: Do you know how to convert text to Upper Case in JavaScript?

Comment: Then the first step would be to search Google or StackOverflow for something like *"JavaScript convert text to Upper Case"*.

Answer (score 2):

you can use CSS by assigning to your textbox style , `text-transform: uppercase;`