# React onChange text input is moving cursor to end of text in input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a bug when I set the value from the state and change the value in a input.

when you write in the input and you try to correct the text the cursor move to the end.

This is my element

```
<div className="campo">
  <p>Nombre</p>
  <div className="campo-input">
    <input
     type="text"
     name="name"
     value={this.state.name}
     onChange={this.handleInputChangeUpperCase}
     />
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my function

```
handleInputChangeUpperCase = (e) => {
    let { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value.toUpperCase() });
  };
```

Working Snippet:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: "Ronaldo",
  };
  
  // This is the function
  handleInputChangeUpperCase = (e) => {
    let { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value.toUpperCase(),
    });
  };
  render() {
  
  // This is the Element
    return (
      <div className="campo">
        <p> Nombre </p>
        <div className="campo-input">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={this.state.name}
            onChange={this.handleInputChangeUpperCase}
          />
          {this.state.name}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: nvm, got it, if we're trying to modify in between there is an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49648061/7427111

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: "Ronaldo",
  };
  
  handleInputChangeUpperCase = (e) => {
  
    // Here is the addition
    const pointer = e.target.selectionStart;
    const element = e.target;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      element.selectionStart = pointer;
      element.selectionEnd = pointer;
    });

    let { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value.toUpperCase(),
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="campo">
        <p> Nombre </p>
        <div className="campo-input">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={this.state.name}
            onChange={this.handleInputChangeUpperCase}
          />
          {this.state.name}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To control where the cursor is in an input field, use `selectionStart`, which indicates where your selected text begins.  As long as you don't set `selectionEnd`, you'll just move the cursor to the desired position.

For instance, let's move to the position "1", just after the first character.  For input "123", that should be "1|23"...

```js
document.getElementById('text-area').selectionStart = 1;
document.getElementById('text-area').focus()
```

```html
  <input id="text-area" type="text" value="123"/>
```

For your situation, if you want the cursor to move to the start of the string, set `.selectionStart = 0`.  If you want it to go back to where it was originally, save the value with `var tempstart = ...selectionStart`, and then restore it after you do the data change, `.selectionStart = tempstart`.

Source: [**Developer.Mozilla.org: HTMLInputElement.setSelectionRange()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange)

Answer (score 1):

If you need just `toUpperCase` as formatting then you can use css instead. It seems the simplest solution is described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3724990/12868043

Answer (score 0):

That behaviour seems to be happening with `.toUpperCase()`;

```
handleInputChangeUpperCase = e => {    
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
};
```

If you don't require the text to be upper case immediately on input, I would apply the method outside of the `setState`